# SQL Server sort order with nonprintable characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ascii

I have a scalar value function that returns a varchar of data containing the ASCII unit seperator Char(31).  I am using this result as part of an Order By clause and attempting to sort in ascending order.

My scalar value function returns results like the following (nonprintable character spelled out for reference)

- ABC
- ABC (CHAR(31)) DEF
- ABC (CHAR(31)) DEF (CHAR(31)) HIJ

I would expect that when I order by ascending the results would be the following:

- ABC
- ABCDEF
- ABCDEFHIJ

instead I am seeing the results as the complete opposite:

- ABCDEFHIJ
- ABCDEF
- ABC

Now I am fairly certain that this has to do with the non-printable characters, but I am not sure why.  Any idea as to why that is the case?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sortorder can be influenced by your [COLLATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) settings. Following script, explicitly using `Latin1_General_CI_AS` as collation orders the items as you would expect.

```
;WITH q (Col) AS (
    SELECT 'ABC' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC' + CHAR(31) + 'DEF' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC' + CHAR(31) + 'DEF' + CHAR(31) + 'HIJ'
)
SELECT  *
FROM    q   
ORDER BY
        Col COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

What collation are you using? You can verify your current database collation settings with

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('master', 'Collation') SQLCollation;
```

Comment: The SQLCollation returns SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: @tribus - That collation indeed seems to order the items the other way arround. You will have to choose between either changing your database collation settings, explicitly add another collation to your order by clauses or change your column definitions to NVARCHAR as mentioned by pete.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to duplicate this behavior in SQL Server 2008 R2 with collation set to `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

If you cannot change your collation settings, set the field to `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`. This solved the issue for me.

Comment: +1 - Indeed it does. I must say that that was a surprise but it does make sense.