# SQL Collation - string comparison not behaving as expected for printable characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I see that:

- the ascii() value and unicode() value of '9' is 57
- the ascii() value and unicode() value of ':' is 58

Therefore, I would expect for the the following test to yield 'This makes sense!'

```
IF '9' < ':'  select 'This makes sense!' as OUTCOME
ELSE select 'Makes no sense to me!' as OUTCOME
```

Alas, it does not.

Now further up the Ascii scale come the letters A (ascii-65) through Z (ascii-90), etc.  If I run the following logic test:

```
   IF '9' < 'A'  select 'This makes sense!' as OUTCOME
   ELSE select 'Makes no sense to me!' as OUTCOME
```

then sanity returns.

Apparently there must be some SQL setting that governs this behavior, but after spending some time searching the internet for an explanation of this behavior, I have not found any.

Comment: Sort order is determined by your collation settings. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107104/sql-server-sort-order-with-nonprintable-characters) for another pertinent SO question (which has an accepted answer that also links to the [MS reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx) on that topic; your assumptions will be reflected in the 'binary' collations).

Comment: #collapsar - you are correct.  Collation setting is the culprit, and your link is helpful for resolution.  I have revamped my question so it will not be considered a duplication.  While looking for answers within Stack Overflow, I came across the same link, but since there were quite a few in the search results, and becauase the title in the link referred to "Non-printable characters", I did not make the connection between its relevance an my situation (since I wasn't working with non-printable characters).  Thx!

Answer (score 1):

You already had the answer you just didn't utilize it.

```
IF ASCII('9') < ASCII(';')
```

Without that you are just comparing strings and the order is determined by the collation of the database, which is certainly not ASCII, but more along the lines of how a dictionary is sorted in most cases.

This link shows the different sort mechanics based on collation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250(v=sql.105).aspx

That said if you insist on sorting according to ASCII then the code above will work.

Comment: #VIncent - Thank you.  Collation setting was the issue.  Unfortunately, using the ASCII() function will not work in my case since I am actually comparing multi-character strings (some of which end in numerical characters).  However when I changed the collation on the table column definitions involved, it straightened the matter out.